# What does the exception mean?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
public class Vector
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public double GetLength() 
        => Geometry.GetLength(this);

    public static Vector Add(Vector first, Vector second) 
        => Geometry.Add(first, second);

    //bool Belongs(Segment segment) 
}

public class Geometry
{
    //double GetLength(Vector point) 

    public static Vector Add(Vector first, Vector second) 
        => new Vector { X = first.X + second.X, Y = first.Y + second.Y };

    // double GetLength(Segment segment)

    //bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector vector, Segment segment)
}

public class Segment
{
    //double GetLength()

    //bool Contains(Vector vector)
}
```

And exception occurred on:

```
new Vector() {X = 1.1, Y = 1.1}.Add(new Vector() {X = 2.2, Y = 2.2}).AlmostEqual(new Vector() {X = 3.3, Y = 3.3})
```

> Method `Add` with appropriate parameters is not found in type `Vector`

What does it mean? (I removed some parts to pass the anti-plagiarism test)

Comment: Pretty much what it says? You don't have a method Add on a Vector object that accepts another Vector to add. Instead you have a static method `Vector.Add()` that you give two Vectors to.

Comment: Probably this was a compilation error, not an exception.

Comment: Why would you have a `Vector Add(Vector first, Vector second)` function in `Geometry` class? `Vector` class seems to be a better fit for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
    public class Vector
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;
    
        public double GetLength() 
            => Geometry.GetLength(this);

        public Vector Add(Vector second) 
            => Geometry.Add(this, second);
    
        //bool Belongs(Segment segment) 
    }
```

Basically I removed the static from this line and the first parameter:

```
public static Vector Add(Vector first, Vector second)
```

Keeping the static, means that you must call it with `Vector.Add`. Without the static, the `Add` function becomes a member of the `Vector` class.

Comment: Yeah Lasse, I hust noticed this. So I removed the first parameter and added `this`